# C++ .obj lnk1120 and lnk2019

Tags: c++

So I'm starting on creating a passer for my c++ program and I have been having this error for awhile where It kept coming up with error for including the .obj file in the project but I have just removed it and I'm still having these errors.

I know this is just a start to the passer of my objects but it still shouldn't be having errors with the .obj file where at the moment the actual method isn't even being called

Here are the errors:

```
error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals \Debug\FP3DA   Framework.exe  FP3DA Framework

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class GameObject __cdecl object(void)" (? object@@YA?AVGameObject@@XZ) referenced in function "public: class GameObject __thiscall passer::fileRead(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?fileRead@passer@@QAE?AVGameObject@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) passer.obj  FP3DA Framework
```

Here is the current incomplete passer code:

```
    #include "passer.h"
using namespace std;


GameObject passer::fileRead(std::string filename)
{
    GameObject object();
    string MaterialLib;
    char fileChar;
    // Open File
    ifstream File;
    File.open(filename.c_str());

    //Check open correctly
    if(!File.good())
        cerr << "Can't open file" << endl;


    //if open
    if(File)
    {
        fileChar = File.get();

        switch(fileChar){

        case 'm': //Material 'mtllib'
            fileChar = File.get();
            while(fileChar != ' ')
                fileChar = File.get();

            fileChar = File.get();

            break;

        case '#':
            fileChar = File.get(); // Next Character from #_
            fileChar = File.get(); // Next Character from #__
                if(File.get() != ' ')
                {
                    //name of object
                }
                else
    //                  File.getline; // Next Line


             break;

        case 'v':
            fileChar = File.get();

            //get vertices

            break;

        case 'vn':
            fileChar = File.get();

            //get vertex normal

            break;

        case 'vt':
            fileChar = File.get();

            //get vertex texture

            break;

        case 'f':
            fileChar = File.get();

            //get faces

            break;

        case ' ': //Skip line
        //   fileChar = File.getline;
             break;
        }


    } //file closed



    //READ MATERIAL FILE



    return object();


}//end of file reader method

    passer::passer(){}

    passer::~passer(){}
```

Comment: Does your GameObject class have an empty constructor? ( GameObject() {} )

Comment: The C++ compiler isn't very good at parsing a declaration like that, an ambiguity in the language syntax.  It thinks your `GameObject object();` declaration is a function prototype.  You probably meant to declare a variable.  Remove the () parentheses.

Comment: @FlorisVelleman its not an empty constructor but I have started to make an overloaded empty constructor. currently still same errors

Comment: @HansPassant yeah that was the issue as it isn't a method but I get an Unhandled exception - Unhandled exception at 0x77202EEC (KernelBase.dll) in FP3DA Framework.exe: 0x0000087D (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x0061DE0C, 0x0061D244).

Comment: Well, sure, debugging is the other 90% of the project.